# How to make Excel cells' values cannot be changed its value via keyboard inputs

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, read-only

Let's take this [simple Excel file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/simple%20permute%20-%20solution.xlsm) as a sample for my question. Please note that it contains permutation macro VBA script.

I want cells in column B to be read-only/unchangable to keyboard inputs i.e. we can't update the cells by entering values from keyboard. But those values are updatable via running the macro `MyPermute`

How can I get there?

Comment: Why don't you just lock the cells/range you want? There are lots of tutorials on the net for this.

Comment: Agreed, lock the cells and add in the unlocking and relocking code to your VBA

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/how-to-protect-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script)

Answer (score 1):

First, write a protect macro that will protect input

```
Sub protect()

Worksheets("sheet1").protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

1. Next go to `review - unprotect sheet` and put in the password to unprotect
2. Now go to `review - allow users to edit ranges`
3. Click `new` and define the range(s) you want users to **be able to edit**
4. Click `permissions` and then `add` and enter the object name `Everyone`
5. Now back out OK - OK - OK
6. Run the `Protect` Macro to protect everything except the ranges defined.
7. Modify your macro to unlock, action, lock (this will work for any macro)

   ```
   Sub MyPermute()
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

   Dim varValues As Variant
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

   Worksheets("sheet1").Unprotect "Password"

   varValues = rng.Cells
   n = UBound(varValues, 1)
   For ii = 1 To 100
       i = MyRandomNum(1, n)
       j = MyRandomNum(1, n)
       subSwap varValues, i, j
   Next ii

   Range("B1:B10") = varValues

   Worksheets("sheet1").protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

   End Sub
   ```

[Modified excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tz2hz3inngbw88e/Copy%20of%20simple%20permute%20-%20solution.xlsm)

Comment: I don't get your last 3 lines

Comment: formatting won't work for me! Add the first line to the beginning of your macro and the third line to the end of your macro. "Stuff" is the macro

Comment: Brilliant @Raystafarian. Thank you very much!